# Make PhantomJS wait for entire page to load before rendering as PDF

Tags: pdf-generation, phantomjs

We cron a `phantomjs rasterize.js http://website.com filename.pdf` which stopped working (blank PDFs) when the website became more "fancy".  If I change it to filename.png it works though.

I tried changing this timeout to 9999 in rasterize and I still get a blank PDF. The default rasterize.js was working before the website switch.

Any ideas what to change/add to rasterize to make it work again?

```js
page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render(output);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 9999);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some problems with this to a year or so ago. For me (if i remember right), it had to do with @media tags. (Again, if i remember right) Pdf's are generated with media print css, while png's are not. Try what happens when you remove all @media print css.

EDIT 23/9/2014

I don't know how problematic this is for you (as how much effort you want to put in it), but if it was me, i would try something like this first:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var args = require('system').args;

var output_file = args[1], url =args[2];

page.viewportSize = { width: 1440, height: 900 };
page.paperSize = {
   format: "A4",
   orientation: "landscape",
   margin: { left: "1cm", right: "1cm", top: "1cm", bottom: "1cm" }
};

console.log(url);

page.onLoadFinished = function (status) {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        try {
            page.evaluate(function () {
                jQuery("link").each(function (i, v) {
                    jQuery(v).attr("media", "all");
                });
            });
            page.render(output_file);
        }
        catch (e) {
            status = e.message;
        }
        console.log(status + ';;' + output_file);
        phantom.exit();
    }, 1000);
}

try {
    page.open(url);
    console.log('loading');
}
catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex.message);
    phantom.exit();
}
```

**Offcourse whatever you want to do within the evaluate function depends on what the contents of the html are.**

A somewhat more decicive way of telling what goes wrong is logging the source of whatever is loaded by using `console.log(page.content);` and then using that to see whats going wrong. (just copy that source into a 'test.html' file and see in browser, remember that (offcourse) links will be broken)

Comment: you mean remove them from the website or remove them from the rasterize file somehow?

Comment: Remove them from the site to test. You can also use javascript ofc. Something like `page.evaluate(function () {
                jQuery("link").each(function (i, v) {
                    jQuery(v).attr("media", "all");
                });
            });` can be evaluated. In my case this helped, but you might `remove()` or something else. (Though commenting stuff out to test is prolly the fastest if you have access)

Comment: Ah, ok.  I don't have access to modify the website unfortunately. So sounds like maybe i'm stuck then.